# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No enabled protocols; SSLv3 is no longer supported and was filtered from the list

Tags: java, android, ssl

Getting this error while hitting API request through volley, It occurs for first time only, Later no error occurs api works fine.Any idea why this is happening.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No enabled protocols; SSLv3 is no longer supported and was filtered from the list
```

Note : this isn't os specific, for this is reproducing on 4.x,5.x ,6.x as well.

Comment: Why close & why minus ? If you arent clear ask. If you can't help , let others do

Comment: Did you fix it? can you share your solution?

Comment: @Mohammad I've fixed this by increasing request time out.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to increase the time out duration of your Volley request. Setting this duration to 20 seconds should fix the problem.

Here is how to do it:

```
//request is an instance of StringRequest or JsonObjectRequest
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciate that. But as you see my comment above I did that and addressed the issue. Thanks